# How to make sure that the given file to multer exists in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, multer, file-exists

First of all I'm working with Node.JS with Express
I made a code that allows me to upload an image with `multer` to a specific directory, and here is a simplified version of it:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'images')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, "some_random_name.jpg")
    },
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (path.extname(file.originalname) != '.jpg')
            return cb("Invalid file type, try uploading a '.jpg' file")
        else
            cb(null, true)
    }
}).single('image')

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
        if (err) 
            return res.status(400).send({ error: err.message })
        else
            dbController.query(/* INSERT INTO images ... */)
        }
    )
})
```

The code works perfectly, but when I give a non existing file to it, it creates a file as if the file existed.
So to solve this I have to make sure that the file really exists before uploading it.
How can I implement this.